# Go - How to copy slice of an interface?

Tags: go, interface, slice, mergesort

I'm trying to implement a simple merge sort using an auxiliary array. I have `type byString []string` that implements the `Less, Swap, and Len` methods. It's basically following Go's `sort` package's interface.

However, I'm having some difficulty choosing the best route to copy the `byString` slice to a temporary array.

Please help me break out of Java's polymorphism world to make it work with Go.

```
func merge(data Interface, lo, mid, hi int) {
  i, j := lo, mid+1

  // How do I copy data's elements to a new slice called aux?
}
```

Comment: `sort.Interface` is designed for `sort.Sort`. It's not a good fit for a non-in-place sort like merge sort.

Comment: You might want to address the question of why you're implementing merge sort in the first place when the `sort` package provides perfectly capable sorting and binary search facilities.

Comment: He could be implementing a typed version of it.

Comment: Yeah, I was rewriting some algorithms I learned in Java to Go. I tried to follow Go's footsteps by copying `sort.Interface` worked, but this is where things got weird. I'm going to stick with working with primitive types for my algorithms. And of course, use Go's packages for actual projects (I rarely have a need for generics with just those anyway)

Answer (score 1):

Use the built-in `copy` function, you just have to declare the new slice as an interface type:

```
type Interface []string

func merge(data Interface, lo, mid, hi int) {
    i, j := lo, mid+1
    var aux Interface = make([]string, len(data), len(data))
    copy(aux, data)
}
```